# Show/hide placeholder when image's src is set

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I hide the `.placeholder` when an `.image`'s `src` is set, and hide the `.image` when the `src` is not set?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="hide-placeholder">
    <img class="placeholder" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5aebae14c6d254621d81f826_placeholder.png">
    <img class="image" src="http://inddc.in/webroot/assets/img/sample/shortcode/logo/1.png">
</label>
<label id="hide-image">
    <img class="placeholder" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5aebae14c6d254621d81f826_placeholder.png">
    <img class="image" src="">
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop on the collection of `.image` and hide the sibling `.placeholder` if the `src` is blank:

```js
$('.image').each(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  
  if (src && src.trim().length > 0) {
    $(this).siblings('.placeholder').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="hide-placeholder">
    <img class="placeholder" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5aebae14c6d254621d81f826_placeholder.png">
    <img class="image" src="http://inddc.in/webroot/assets/img/sample/shortcode/logo/1.png">
</label>
<label id="hide-image">
    <img class="placeholder" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/57e5747bd0ac813956df4e96/5aebae14c6d254621d81f826_placeholder.png">
    <img class="image" src="">
</label>
```

Comment: This just hid the images in the `#hide-image` container. For every instance where `placeholder` and `image` are siblings, the `placeholder` will be hidden when the `image` `src` is set, and vice versa

Comment: @KyleUnderhill -- I did not get you right. Do you want to hide the `.image` as well if `.placeholder`'s src is blank?

Comment: Yes only show the image that has a `src`, and give `.image` priority if both are set.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill -- Please see my update. Does it work right now?

Answer (score 1):

A different approach

CSS to hide if src is empty

```
img[src=""] {
   display: none;
}
```

JavaScript to hide placeholder

```
$(".image[src='']").siblings(".placeholder").hide();
```